# Vimeo seekTo jumps to plus older seekTo

Tags: vimeo, seek

I've set seekTo to 30 seconds. When page loads it's directly seeking to 30 secs as required.'

Problem:

1. It plays automatically as it seeks to 30 secs on load. (it should seekto 30 secs but should be paused by default)
2. While playing when I drag further, then video plays from the dragged secs + 30 secs (it should not add old seekTo time when I drag, instead it should continue playing from the dragged sec)(for example: when I drag it to 1min 20secs its simply jumps to 1min 50secs by adding older seekTo parameter. It should not happen)

Spent lot of time googling it but no luck yet. Please help me to fix it.

Browser: IE 9, FF 17

Link: jsfiddle.net/w9ycw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be resolved now. We (Vimeo) pushed out an update a while ago that addressed this issue.

The issue was due to managing the offset of seek requests that fall outside of the buffered region, and that not being reset after subsequent seek requests based on the buffered region of the video.

Please let us know if you run into any other issues while working with the player.

Thanks.